# When does the topological boundary of an embedded manifold equal its manifold boundary?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose I embed a manifold-with-boundary $M$ in some $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Are there conditions (necessary, sufficient, or both) that can help determine when the topological boundary of $M$ is equal to the manifold boundary?

By "topological boundary," I'm referring to $\text{Bd } M$, which is the closure minus the interior (relative to $\mathbb{R}^n$).

By "manifold boundary," I mean the boundary $\partial M$ that is specified in the definition of "manifold-with-boundary."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you embed a smooth $m$-manifold $M$ smoothly in $\mathbb{R}^n$
then the "topological boundary" of $M$ is the closure of $M$. As
locally each point of $M$ has a neighbourhood in $\mathbb{R}^n$
where $M$ looks like $\mathbb{R}^m$, then no point of $M$ is interior.

When $m=n$ and $M$ is compact then, yes (at least in the smooth case)
the topological and manifold boundaries coincide.

I expect the above hold for topological embeddings but won't swear
to it; they need not be locally flat (see nasties like the Alexander
horned sphere),

Comment: wait re 1st sentence Bd M equals $\overline M$ ?

Comment: In the first paragraph it is implicitly assumed that $m<n$ and $M$ is a manifold without boundary (which is then contradicted by the 2nd paragraph). All in all, alas, the answer is sloppy (even though, highly upvoted) and the reader should refrain from using it without proper understanding of the subject.

Comment: @MoisheKohan He implicitly assumes $m<n$ in the first paragraph because he says that $M$ has no interior points, right?

Comment: @Filippo: Right.

Answer (score 4):

In order to complement and clarify Chapman's answer:

For a topological manifold $M$, possibly with boundary, I will use the notation $\partial M$ to denote its boundary and $int(M)=M\setminus \partial M$ its interior (both are understood here in the sense of manifold topology).

For a subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$, I will use the notation $Int(Y)$ to denote its topological interior, i.e. the union of all open subsets of $X$ contained in $Y$. Accordingly, I let $Fr(Y)$ denote the **frontier** of $Y$ in $X$, which is $cl(Y)\setminus Int(Y)$. (I prefer the terminology "frontier" to that of "topological boundary," which appears in the OP.)

Suppose now that $M$ is an $m$-dimensional topological manifold, possibly with boundary, $m\le n$, and $f: M\to E^n$ is a topological embedding. Then the following proposition relates the boundary $M$ and the frontier of $f(M)$ in $E^n$:

Proposition. 1. Suppose that $m< n$. Then:

(a)  $f(M)\subset Fr(f(M))$.

(b) If $M$ is compact, then $f(M)= Fr(f(M))$.

2. Suppose that $m=n$. Then:

(a) $f(int(M))= Int(f(M))$ and $f(\partial M)\subset Fr(f(M))$.

(b) If $M$ is compact, then $f(\partial M)=  Fr(f(M))$. If $M$ is noncompact, this equality might fail.

Proof. 1a is an immediate consequence of the invariance of domain theorem: An open subset of $E^m$ cannot be homeomorphic to an open subset of $E^n$, implying that $Int(f(M))$ is empty.

1b. Since $M$ is compact, $f(M)$ is closed in  $E^n$, hence, $Fr(f(M))= f(M)\setminus Int(f(M))= f(M)$.

2a.  $f(int(M))\subset Int(f(M))$ is a consequence of the invariance of domain theorem again. Suppose that $y=f(x)\in Int(f(M))$. Then there is an open ball neighborhood $V$ of $y$ contained in $R^n$, By applying the invariance of domain theorem to $f^{-1}: f(M)\to M$, we see that $x$ is an interior point of $M$. Thus, $f(int(M))= Int(f(M))$. In other words, $f(\partial M)\cap Int(f(M))=\emptyset$. It follows that
$f(\partial M)\subset Fr(f(M))$.

2b. Since $M$ is compact, $f(M)$ is closed in  $E^n$, hence, $Fr(f(M))=f(M)\setminus Int(f(M))= f(M)\setminus f(int(M))= f(\partial M)$.

To get an example of a noncompact manifold where the equality fails, take, for instance $M=[0,1)$ and $f$ the identity inclusion $M\to {\mathbb R}=E^1$. Then $Fr(M)= \{0, 1\}$, while $\partial M= \{0\}$. Similar examples exist in all dimensions.  qed

Comment: What is $E^n$ ?

Comment: @Filippo: $n$-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: I.e. an affine space with an $n$-dimensional real inner product space as translation space?

Comment: @Filippo: Right.

Comment: Regarding your example: Obviously a subset that is not closed can not have have manifold boundary equal to its topological boundary, since the manifold boundary is always a subset of the manifold itself, whereas the topological boundary is not in this case. But it would be interesting to see closed subsets where the two boundaries are not equal.

Comment: @Filippo: My answer explains why they are always equal for closed subsets: I give the proof for compact subsets but the argument is general.

Comment: So in the propositions 1(b) and 2(b) you could have written "closed" instead of "compact"?

Comment: @Filippo: More precisely, assuming that $f(M)$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. So it seems like your proposition does not allow us to say something about general submanifolds, right? Only about submanifolds of euclidean spaces.

Comment: Which would be totally sufficient, I'm just curious.

Comment: @Filippo The proofs are local, so you can replace $E^n$ by any $n$-manifold without boundary.